# How to Remove particular changing text in from a DataFrame column in Python?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace, python-re

I have a dataframe containing column 'test'. It looks like this:

```
Column Test 
'[ABC: 814.6] text text text text [text:123]'
'[ABC: 432.9] text text [ABC: 433] text text [text:123]'
'[ABC: 1] text text text [342:] text [text:123]'
```

I want to remove all the **'[ABC: XXX.X]'** parts. 
I know how to replace 'static' text, like this:

```
df['Test_New'] = df['Test'].str.replace("[ABC: XXX.X]", '')
```

however since the XXX.X are changing, i have no clue how to solve this.

Desired output:

```
Column Test 
' text text text text [text:123]'
' text text  text text [text:123]'
' text text text [342:] text [text:123]'
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Str.replace supports regex. Details in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @ZaxR's comment, `str.replace` supports regex.

```py
df['Test_New'] = df['Test'].str.replace(r"\[ABC: [\d]{1,3}(?:.\d)?\]", '')
```

Comment: It looks likes this is working! Do you know if it is also possible to get this working if we do have 2 decimals? For example '[ABC: 751.96]'. Many thanks @ywbaek

Comment: @Roverflow, you just need to specify that `df['Test_New'] = df['Test'].str.replace(r"\[ABC: [\d]{1,3}(?:.[\d]{1,2})?\]", '')`